# What is the preferred Visual Odometry package: viso2_ros or fovis_ros?

Tags: ros, imu, kinect, phidgets, viso2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been experimenting with fovis and viso2 in order to acquire visual odometry using the Kinect and Phidgets IMU.  I noticed that the parameters are pretty much the same for both packages. Can anyone tell me which one they prefer and why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57869/what-is-the-preferred-visual-odometry-package:-viso2_ros-or-fovis_ros?/) by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-12**:
Which works better for you?

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-03-12**:
I'm getting better results from fovis_ros because it uses both depth and rgb.  There are tf issues if you rely on the tf odom->base_link that fovis publishes.  Errors arise if the messages are not perfectly in sync...

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-03-12**:
Please report any bugs regarding fovis_ros [here](https://github.com/srv/fovis/issues/new).

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-03-12**:
I don't think the bug is in fovis_ros necessarily.  The time stamp syncing between messages becomes delayed via a main launch file that launches every node for the robot.  I believe this is the processor's fault.  To compensate, I added a rate.sleep() in the odometer_base.hpp, increased the queue...

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-03-12**:
...to 10 and changed how fast the WallDuration was requesting synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of the main differences is that fovis_ros supports mono+depth input as well as stereo and viso2_ros supports mono and stereo (but no mono+depth). If you use just a kinect, you will likely get better results using fovis_ros as with viso2_ros you can only use the mono_odometer which has several drawbacks (needs features on the floor and needs to know pitch and height of camera). If you use a stereo camera you can try both algorithms and look which works best for you.

fovis_ros offers a little more introspection which eases the tuning of parameters (compare [FovisInfo](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/fovis_ros/html/msg/FovisInfo.html) to [VisoInfo](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/viso2_ros/html/msg/VisoInfo.html)). It also has keyframe selection built in. For viso2_ros we hacked a solution to prevent drift on top of the library which is not very well tested.

Long story short:
If you have a kinect, use fovis_ros. If you have a stereo camera, try both and look what works best for you. If you have a mono camera, use viso2_ros.

Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-04-17**:
I actually started using ccny_rgbd and it has proved to be a nice complement to wheel encoder odometry.  It is very lightweight which is desirable for my system and doesn't throw a lot of warnings and errors.